# Guardar clientes dentro de uma ArrayList

Tags: java

Levando em consideração as classes abaixo, como eu posso - dentro da classe Banco - armazenar dentro da ArrayList todos os meus clientes?

**Banco**

```
public class Banco {
    private ArrayList<Conta> contas;

    public Banco() {
        contas = new ArrayList<Conta>();
    }
}
```

**Cliente**

```
public class Cliente {
    private String nome;
    private String telefone;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
}
```

**Conta**

```
public class Conta {
    private int numero;
    private double saldo;
    private Cliente cli;

    public Conta() {

    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }
    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
    public Cliente getCli() {
        return cli;
    }
    public void setCli(Cliente cli) {
        this.cli = cli;
    }
}
```

Comment: O importante é funcionar :)

Comment: Poderia colocar o código da parte onde cria os clientes, as contas e o banco?

Comment: Os objetos `Conta` já possuem uma referência ao seu objeto `Cliente`, sendo assim o banco não armazena os clientes, mas armazena as contas que possuem referências aos seus respectivos clientes. Não tem nada de errado nessa ideia e a modelagem das classes está correta, não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: Meu objetivo é criar um método dentro da classe Banco que liste nomes e telefones dos clientes que possuem saldo negativo

Comment: Hum sim, adicionei esse método na minha resposta. Confesso que inicialmente fiquei meio confuso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levando em consideração as classes da forma que está, você pode criar um método na classe `Banco` que retorna todos os clientes em um `ArrayList`.

```
public ArrayList<Cliente> listarClientes(){
    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList();
    for(Conta conta : contas){
        clientes.add(conta.getCli());
    }
    return clientes;
}



public ArrayList<Cliente> listarInadimplentes(){
    ArrayList<Cliente> inadimplentes = new ArrayList();
    for(Conta conta : contas){
        if(conta.getSaldo()<0)
            inadimplentes.add(conta.getCli());
    }
    return clientes;
}
```

Comment: Esse código funciona, mas não segue as recomendacões de referencia por Interface. Ou seja, deveria retornar um tipo List<E> ao invés de ArrayList<E>, outro ponto é que há um raw type ao instanciar o ArrayList.
Deveria ser ArrayList<Cliente>();   ou   ArrayList<>(); Parao Java 7. Caso o contrário haverá warnings no seu código.

Comment: Na verdade eu quiz facilitar uma vez que ela instanciou contas como arrayslist.

Answer (score 0):

Usa um método na classe Banco similar ao `setCli()` da classe Conta.
Tipo assim:

```
public class Banco {
    private ArrayList<Conta> contas;

    public Banco() {
        contas = new ArrayList<Conta>();
    }

    public void setConta(Conta conta) {
        contas.add(conta)
    }
}
```